# How to avoid overlap when working with the habitats baseline map layer on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, error, overlapping-features, polygon-creation, habitat-modeling

I have recently been working with Natural England's Net Gain Habitat mapping QGIS software. I have plotted baseline habitats, filling out the proposed habitat too.

In my previous experience of QGIS I was able to draw a basic outline of a feature overlapping other features and it would cut the share drawn to avoid overlap with other polygons. This saved me a lot of time when mapping individual habitats as I didn't have to map the features so closely.

I have gone through the advanced configuration tool selecting all layers, avoid overlap and allow snapping as I previously but it doesn't seem to work on Natural England's document.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure of defining avoiding overlap here:

[image]
In previous versions of the snapping options dialog box, you just had to put a check mark on the avoid overlap of the polygon layer (1). Now you have to specify the same parameter at (2).